# Android Design - How remove the space between my image and edit text?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I have given my layout xml below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >


    <TableRow>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:stretchColumns="0" >

            <TableRow>


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/backwithborder"
                    android:ems="5" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"
                    android:layout_weight="1" 
                    android:layout_height="35dip"
                    android:background="@drawable/backwithborder" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_down" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="@color/list_seperator" />

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/xBtnContacts"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pick Contacts" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="@color/list_seperator" />

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try out somthing like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="5" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/xBtnContacts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/table"
    android:text="Pick Contacts" />
<View
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/xBtnContacts"
    android:background="#ff0000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In your xml how to add a line at bottom. Because whenever i try to add something at bottom, It disppears.

Comment: Hello Naveen i Have edited according to ur need. see updated answer.

Comment: there is no opening tag of relative layout

Answer (score 0):

try moving the gravity and setting your width and height to fill_parent

```
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/no_image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The spacing between image and edit text is due to "Pick Contacts" as in table layout widht of one row depend on other ........ (try with give the width 40dp to button for test it)

I 'll suggest to use the Linear layout and Relative layout to make this UI....

Comment: Where is Pick Contacts in my xml?

Comment: this is button havind id android:id="@+id/xBtnContacts"